# Angular scope not updated on rootscope event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm currently making a notification banner for my application but my data does not refresh in the dom when I update after listening to a rootscope event.

I've tried to put that code into $timeout or use $digest and even $apply and it does not work.

Here is the place where I update my viewmodel in the controller:

```
const event = $rootScope.$on('notifications.updated', (event, notifications) => {
        const notification = notifications ? notifications.values().next().value : null;

        if (notification) {
            _setNotification(notification);
        } else {
            _resetNotification();
        }

        vm.enabled = !!notification;
    });
```

Here the directive declaration:

```
function notificationBannerDirective() {
    return {
        restrict        : 'E',
        replace         : true,
        templateUrl     : 'templates/directives/notificationBanner.html',
        scope           : {},
        controller      : notificationBannerController,
        controllerAs    : 'vm',
        bindToController: true
    };
}
```

Here is the full declaration of the directive and the controller:

https://pastebin.com/QpgLvhR3

And here is the template:

```
<div
class="notification-banner {{vm.enabled ? 'show' : ''}} {{vm.size || vm.ConstNotifications.sizes.MEDIUM}} {{vm.level || vm.ConstNotifications.levels.MINOR}}">
<p class="message">{{vm.message}}</p>
<p class="action" ng-if="vm.action" ng-click="vm.action.callback()">{{vm.action.message}}</p>
<a class="button button-icon icon ion-close" ng-if="vm.canClose" ng-click=""></a>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Seems alright. What does your tpl look like?

Comment: I added it into the question ;)

Comment: Can you 1) verify that enabled is being bound correctly by manually changing it's value in code and 2) verify that the event callback is being reached when the event is emitted.

Comment: In fact if I bind my data outside of the rootscope event everything works well and i can confirm you that the event is being called and the viewModel is being filled

Comment: From what I have seen I can't tell. Could you reproduce in plunkr. See my plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/p6Fp9onv5bBMeWbx89EO?p=preview

Comment: I checked your plunkr and it seems to be the same as my code and it works well.
It's surely related to my app context...

Comment: Thanks for helping me i'll try to find why it's not working